# The name 'xDocument' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I get an error "The name 'xDocument' does not exist in the current context" when writing some code for RSS feed reader. What is wrong here with xDocument?
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace RSSreaderAPP
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ReadRss();
            }
        }

        private void ReadRss()
        {
            string RssFeedUrl = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/neowin-main";
            List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
                xDoc = xDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
                var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                             select new
                             {
                                 title = x.Element("title").Value,
                                 link = x.Element("link").Value,
                                 pubDate = x.Element("publish date").Value,
                                 description = x.Element("description").Value
                             });
                if (items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var i in items)
                    {
                        Feeds f = new Feeds
                        {
                            Title = i.title,
                            Link = i.link,
                            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                            Description = i.description
                        };
                        feeds.Add(f);
                    }
                }
                gridViewRSS.DataSource = feeds;
                gridViewRSS.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is to avoid annoying message.

Comment: should be xDoc = xDoc.Load(RssFeedUrl); xDocument is not declared anywhere

Comment: You need `xDoc.Load` instead of `xDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl)`, you haven't defined `xDocument` anywhere in your code

Comment: Shouldn't that be `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes.

Comment: After using Sriram's solution I get this exception "$exception {"The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
" Please don't close this thread yet.
This is what it says in the exception pop-up 
"An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in RSSreaderAPP.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: Ok I solved it by removing a free space in pubDate = x.Element("publish date").Value,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc = xDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
```

to

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
```

and also `pubDate = x.Element("publish date").Value`,

to

```
pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,

private void ReadRss()
{
    string RssFeedUrl = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/neowin-main";
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        //XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        //xDoc = xDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("link").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         description = x.Element("description").Value,
                     });
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    Description = i.description,
                };
                feeds.Add(f);
            }
        }
        gridViewRSS.DataSource = feeds;
        gridViewRSS.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, get rid of that try/catch. `try {/* code */} catch (Exception ex){throw;}` is the same thing as `/* code */`.